# Vectorization of tempered fractional differencing calculation

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I am trying to speed up this approximation of tempered fractional differencing.
This controls the long/quasi-long memory of a time series. Given that the first for loop is iterative, I don't know how to vectorize it. Also,the output of the attempted vectorization is a little off from the unaltered raw code. Thank you for your help.

Raw Code

```
tempfracdiff= function (x,d,eta) {

n=length(x);x=x-mean(x);PI=numeric(n)
PI[1]=-d;TPI=numeric(n);ydiff=x

for (k in 2:n) {PI[k]=PI[k-1]*(k-1-d)/k}
for (j in 1:n) {TPI[j]=exp(-eta*j)*PI[j]}
for (i in 2:n) {ydiff[i]=x[i]+sum(TPI[1:(i-1)]*x[(i-1):1])}
return(ydiff)                  }
```

Attempted Vectorization

```
tempfracdiffFL=function (x,d,eta) {

n=length(x);x=x-mean(x);PI=numeric(n)
PI[1]=-d;TPI=numeric(n);ydiff=x

for (k in 2:n) {PI[k]=PI[k-1]*(k-1-d)/k}
TPI[1:n]=exp(-eta*1:n)*PI[1:n]
ydiff[2:n]=x[2:n]+sum(TPI[1:(2:n-1)]*x[(2:n-1):1])
return(ydiff)          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PI, you can use `cumprod`:

```
k <- 1:n
PI <- cumprod((k-1-d)/k)
```

TPI may be expressed without indices:

```
TPI <- exp(-eta*k)*PI
```

And `ydiff` is `x` plus the convolution of `x` and `TPI`:

```
ydiff <- x+c(0,convolve(x,rev(TPI),type="o")[1:n-1])
```

So, putting it all together:

```
mytempfracdiff = function (x,d,eta) {
  n <- length(x)
  x <- x-mean(x)
  k <- 1:n
  PI <- cumprod((k-1-d)/k)
  TPI <- exp(-eta*k)*PI
  x+c(0,convolve(x,rev(TPI),type="o")[1:n-1])
}
```

Test case example

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
d <- 0.1
eta <- 0.5

all.equal(mytempfracdiff(x,d,eta), tempfracdiff(x,d,eta))
# [1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mytempfracdiff(x,d,eta), tempfracdiff(x,d,eta))
```

```
    Unit: microseconds
                          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq
     mytempfracdiff(x, d, eta) 186.220 198.0025  211.9254  207.473  219.944
       tempfracdiff(x, d, eta) 961.617 978.5710 1117.8803 1011.257 1061.816
          max neval
      302.548   100
     3556.270   100
```

Answer (score 1):

For PI[k], `Reduce` is helpful

```
n <- 5; d <- .3
fun <- function( a,b ) a * (b-1-d)/b
Reduce( fun, c(1,1:n), accumulate = T )[-1] # Eliminates PI[0]

[1] -0.30000000 -0.10500000 -0.05950000 -0.04016250 -0.02972025
```